# Как сделать вторую колонку, занимающая все пустое пространство по ширине?

Tags: html, css

Есть родительский блок, и 2 дочерних. Первая колонка фиксированной ширины. Как сделать, чтобы вторая колонка занимала все пустое пространство по ширине? Родительский блок имеет свойство `display: flex`.

Я делаю так, но думаю, есть более правильное решение.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.column_one {
  width: 400px;
}

.column_two {
  width: calc(100% - 400px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column_one"></div>
  <div class="column_two"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

А `flex-grow` уже не устраивает?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  
  min-height: 100px;
}

.column_one {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #DC4242;
}

.column_two {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column_one"></div>
  <div class="column_two"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если поддержка только вовременных браузеров, то можно так

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.wrapper > div{
  
  min-height: 30px;
}

.column_one {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #f00;
}

.column_two {
    width: calc(100% - 400px);
    background-color: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="column_one"></div>
    <div class="column_two"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: И чем это отличается от моего варианта? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто упростить себе задачу, задавая ширину в переменной, вот так:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 20px;
}

.column_one {
  width: var(--width);
  background: red;
}

.column_two {
  width: calc(100% - var(--width));
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="--width: 400px;">
  <div class="column_one"></div>
  <div class="column_two"></div>
</div>
```

Не думаю что есть более правильное решение. Можно конечно что-то с `inline-block`'ом сделать, но вряд ли это поможет, т.к. вы используете flex.

Answer (score 0):

Так пойдёт?))

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.column_one {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.column_two {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column_one"></div>
  <div class="column_two"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Но есть один минус - это работает пока вы не зададите родителю flex-wrap: wrap;